# Why cant i use this code to use digital signature on my file?

Tags: php, command

```
$lol = system("sudo gpg --clearsign asd.txt;");
```

Is it because I need the password for the gpg??

sudoers:

root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. Please always provide the error messages you encounter while running the code you post, as it can always be specific to your system.

Comment: The return value of the command is 2. Using CENTOS

Comment: I Changed the command to this :                                                              $lol = shell_exec("echo $passphrase | sudo gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --clearsign asd.txt");

Comment: Still does not work even though the --passphrase-fd 0 suppose to make the passphrase take in the front one

Comment: And i used visudo to change apache to NOPASSSWD:ALL

Comment: I changed my visudo to www-data to NOPASSWD:ALL but still doesnt work

Comment: Can you update your question with this sudoers line ?

Comment: Did you get errors in the error.log file of your website ? Errors in the system log ?

Comment: 0 errors just that the return value is just 2

Comment: i cant su www-data as they say user does not exsist

Comment: Did su apache works ?

Comment: i had to su -s /bash/bin apache for it to work. I tried the same method for www-data usr but it doesnt work

Comment: i tried the passphrase line too but the value still returned me 2. It works in the command prompt just fine though , just that when i put in into php code it does not

Comment: Before asking php to execute a command, please verify that this command actually work on your shell with your usual user, then on the shell with the target user (apache in our case) then only use php to call it.

Did you already see this command working ?

Comment: Yes it works on the bash shell when i use sudo with the command

Comment: To get it working from php, you should be able to run your commands without typing any pass : this had to work from shell :
`su -s /bash/bin apache ;
sudo gpg --passphrase 12345  --clearsign asd.txt;`

Comment: I put the exact code into the thing but still return value 2

Answer (score 0):

You can't use sudo in this case, as it would ask for a password.
You can use sudoers to avoid the need of the password, only for some choosen commands, only for choosen some users, for security .

Here is some sample [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers), look for your OS one.

Please provide the error that may have occured (see both apache and bash error logs), as other problems can hide behind this one.

**Edit :** 
In your case, the command you want to be sudoed without ask for pass is 
"gpg --clearsign"

The user that actually launch this command is "www-data", not apache, so update your sudoers accordingly and this will work.

**Edit2 :**
Let's simulate the php behavior. Php (apache in fact, so www-data user) has to sudo command. Let's do this in bash :

```
su www-data
sudo gpg --clearsign asd.txt;
```

Can you see something new ?
Was the root password asked ?

Answer (score 0):

Another password related problem, but on the gpg side this time :

gpg is asking for a password when decrypting a file, with a prompt.

As in php we can't type the pass in the prompt, we will have to send this pass in the command, with this argument :

```
--passphrase 12345
```

So your command shall become, with the correct pass, of course :

```
$lol = system("sudo gpg --passphrase 12345 --clearsign asd.txt;");
```